# What's the latest, stable version of Ubuntu that doesn't use Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I'm looking for the latest, stable version of Ubuntu that uses Gnome 2. As much as I understand, newest, stable version - 11.04 - is using Unity... and that's new [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).

[Is Unity a Desktop Environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19573/is-unity-a-desktop-environment) helped a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ubuntu 11.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/) is the latest version that uses Gnome 2 (Although this isn't exactly what you want, as you actually are talking about gnome-panel, which 11.04 uses Unity), but this version is no longer supported.

[Ubuntu 10.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/) is the latest version that uses gnome-panel by default, but this version is no longer supported.

[Ubuntu 10.04.2](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.04.2/) is the latest LTS release that uses gnome-panel, which is supported until April 2013 (for the Desktop) and April 2015 (for the server)

Comment: 11.04 is EOL, so is 10.10.  Only 10.04.2 is the latest supported release without Unity by default.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 11.04 does use Unity by default, but you can change back to Gnome 2/gnome-panel by choosing the Ubuntu Classic Session option in the login screen.

Comment: Is it possible to get Gnome 3 on it? Without additional installing maybe?

Comment: You can get Gnome 3 on 11.04, although it complete breaks Unity on 11.04 (since it's Gnome 3, not Gnome 2). See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3

Comment: @daGrevis Please ask that as a seperate question :D

Answer (score 4):

You can have the classic look by doing this:

- [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.10 use gnome 2 standard in ubuntu 11.04 you can still switch to claccis.

Answer (score -2):

you can have 12.04 with Gnome2, here my:
[image]

here a little guide: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: Wow wo no.. that's Gnome 3 Classic not Gnome 2 c'mon it says it in the article..